# LINQ Query Except not working, List<long?> vs. List<long>

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

What I'm trying to do is narrow the results of a query that I will use to databind later on. I want to get all of the ProgramIds that are used in my gridview, and remove them from the datasource of my dropdownlist (ie, so that a user cannot choose to create and insert an object into the gridview of the same ProgramId as one that already exists)

Here's some code:

```
var query = from goals in DataContext.Goals
            select goals;
var query2 = (from goals in query.AsEnumerable()
              select goals.ProgramId).ToList(); //List<long?>
var query3 = (from progs in DataContext.Programs
              select progs.ProgramId).ToList(); //List<long>
var cgps = query3.Except(query2);
```

And I'm getting these errors on `var cgps = query3.Except(query2);` :

> Error 29  'System.Collections.Generic.List' does not contain a definition for 'Except' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Except(System.Linq.ParallelQuery, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments  C:...\Shmeh\Shmeh\Shmeh\this.aspx.cs   24  226 Project
>
> Error 30  Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery'    C:...\Shmeh\Shmeh\Shmeh\this.aspx.cs   24  226 Project

If you have any idea how to validly do what I'm trying to do, any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx) requires that the sequences are both of the same type.  Try casting the `long` list to `long?`:

```
var query3 = (from progs in DataContext.Programs
              select (long?)progs.ProgramId).ToList(); //List<long?>
```

Answer (score 5):

You're getting this error because `long?` is not the same type as `long`.  `Except` requires both enumerable objects to be of the same type.

What you could do is remove the null values from query2 and convert ProgramId to `long`

```
var query2 = (from goals in query.AsEnumerable()
              where goals.ProgramId.HasValue
              select goals.ProgramId.Value).ToList()
```

Answer (score 3):

try

```
var cgps = query3.Cast<long?>().Except(query2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var cgps = DataContext.Programs.Select(p => p.ProgramId)
    .Except(DataContext.Goals.Where(g => g.ProgramId.HasValue).Select(g => g.ProgramId.Value));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work for you.

```
var query2 = (from goals in query.AsEnumerable()
              select goals.ProgramId).ToList() as List<long?>;

var query3 = (from progs in DataContext.Programs
              select (long?)progs.ProgramId).ToList() as List<long?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why he/she deleted their answer, but I'm using this:

```
dropdownlist.DataSource = (
            from progs in DataContext.Programs
            where !(from goals in query.AsEnumerable()
                    select goals.ProgramId)
                   .Contains(progs.ProgramId)
            select progs.Name).ToList();
dropdownlist.DataBind();
```

Because it doesn't require me to use multiple query variables, although the answer I accepted worked as well with what I had.